# Why does my post not meet the quality standards?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure why I was unable to post a question to this forum a moment ago. I put these facts:

Title: Difference between askubuntu.com and ubuntuforums.org?
Msg: What is the difference between askubuntu.com and ubuntuforums.org?

So now I have two questions, the only one above, and a second one why my previous post didn't meet the quality standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Forums has a lot of answers to questions about old, unsupported releases of Ubuntu that don't work anymore. Ask Ubuntu also has many obsolete answers, but a smaller percentage of the answers on Ask Ubuntu are obsolete. Ask Ubuntu is maintained by the community, and obsolete answers can be updated either by someone editing the answer or by the person who originally posted the answer editing his own answer. If an obsolete answer can't be improved by editing, then a new answer can be posted to prevent the original question from becoming a useless source of obsolete information.

Comment: Thank you, nice explination

Answer (score 1):

Seek first, ask questions later...

1. https://askubuntu.com/help/quality-standards-error
2. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic
3. And for your next question:   https://askubuntu.com/help/searching
4. And the one after that: https://askubuntu.com/help/

Comment: Hi yes I already read the guide in bullet point 1, hence the question. And as for the search, i searched for askubuntu vs ubuntuforums, and the results were0, see below. Again, hence my question

Search
 
0 results
relevance newest votes active

Your search returned no matches.
.

Comment: @johnsmith Its because AskUbuntu is about Ubuntu, not about the site, *this meta site* is about the site itself, you  may search here but won't find much answers as *meta* site is also about this site and not ubuntuforums.org !